# woocommerace after checkout field is no validate ...when un check create account its still ask for full fill and validation

Tags: wordpress

woocommerace after checkout field is no validate ...when un check  create account its still ask for full fill and validation error  i want when i checked create account then  this validation will work
before un checked why this is asking for validation hope got my point

function

```
    public function wooc_create_dobc_fields() {
    $birthday_label    = get_option( 'label_birthday' );
    $birthday_required = get_option( 'required_fields_dobc' );
    if ( empty( $birthday_label ) ) {
        $birthday_label = 'Enter Your Date Of Birthday';
    }   
    $user_id   = get_current_user_id();
    $show_date = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'dobc_date_field', true );
    get_user_meta( $user_id, 'dobc_date_field', true );
    ?>
    <div class="create-account">
        <p>
            <label for="label_birthday"><?php echo esc_attr( $birthday_label, 'dobc' ); ?>
            <?php if ( 'yes' === $birthday_required ) : ?>
                <span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </label>
        <?php $required = ( 'yes' === $birthday_required ) ? 'required' : ''; ?>
            <input type="date" class="input-text" name="dobc_date_field" id="date of birthd " value="<?php echo esc_html( $show_date ); ?>"  <?php echo esc_html( $required ); ?> />
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'birthday_nonce_action_checkout', 'birday_fields_checkout_nonce' ); ?>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
    <?php
}
```

hooks

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', array( $this, 'wooc_create_dobc_fields' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', array( $this,'my_custom_checkout_field_process' ) );
```

call back validation

```
public function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
// Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( isset($_POST['dobc_date_field']  ) && empty($_POST['dobc_date_field'] )) 
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please Enter Date Of Birthday' ), 'error' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution from my team leader
hooks

```
if ( 'yes' === $birthday_required ) {
        if ( 'yes' == get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) {
                add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', array( $this, 'my_custom_checkout_field_process' ) );
```

call back function

```
public function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['birday_fields_checkout_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['birday_fields_checkout_nonce'], 'birthday_nonce_action_checkout' ) ) )
    ) {
        print 'Sorry, your nonce did not verify.';
        exit;
    }
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( isset( $_POST['createaccount'] ) && empty( $_POST['dobc_date_field'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please Enter Date Of Birthday' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```